# Android Interstitial ad not working with banner

Tags: android, admob

So I've got a weird situation.

I have an app that has a banner, an interstital, and a rewards video ad all on the same view.

Before you freak, the banner ad shows all the time and I want to switch between the other 2 types instead of always showing just reward videos etc.

So banner shows and the other 2 show on a button press.

The ads work great by themselves. I can get all ads working. But the issue comes up when I want to show the interstital ad instead of the rewards video.

I have logic that simply checks which to show and shows 1. The video ads work and always have. The baner also works fine. The interstital doesn't work at all unless I immediately show it unpon loaded.

For example. If my code says this :

```
private void buildInterstial()
    {
        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.button_add_unit_id));
        mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded()
            {
                EnableDisableButton("enable");
                mInterstitialAd.show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                AdClosed();
                EnableDisableButton("disable");
            }
        });
    }
```

It works. It shows right after it loads. If however I move the show to that button click like this:

```
if(showReward && mAd.isLoaded()) {
            mAd.show();
        }
        else if(showReward && mInterstitialAd.isLoaded() )
        {
            mInterstitialAd.show();
        }

}
```

It doesn't work. Instead the reward video works and the interstital  always says its not loaded but that doesn't make sense since it was fired from the ads on load method.

Again. If I have either the video ads OR the interstital everything works. But if I want to switch between the 2 only the rewards videos work as the interstital  always says false when checked if loaded.

The Android monitor windows says :

```
W/MessageQueue: Handler (android.os.Handler) {15b0fa22} sending message to a 
Handler on a dead thread
The webview is destroyed. Ignoring action.
Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid
W/ExoPlayerImplInternal: Sent message(1) after release. Message ignored.
```

I've check all over google but no one seems to have the same issue.

I've checked :
[Admob interstitial ad not working in this situation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34553649/admob-interstitial-ad-not-working-in-this-situation)

[android interstitial ad is not diplaying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27068037/android-interstitial-ad-is-not-diplaying)

[Android Interstitial Ad does not show](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41660900/android-interstitial-ad-does-not-show)

https://github.com/delight-im/Android-AdvancedWebView/issues/35

[Android Webview: Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33083066/android-webview-cannot-call-determinedvisibility-never-saw-a-connection-for/38547087)

and more.

Can anyone help with this? For now I just show the vids but I'd like to be able to choose.

I don't know if it hates my banner or if something hates me setting the buttons visibility when the ad is closed or what.

Thanks.

Comment: What is showReward?

Comment: Just a bool that says if it should display an ad.

I just checked and Android studio keeps showing "Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 31037".

Comment: You need to request a new interstitial after you present it. You can not reuse them. Also, where are you declaring `mInterstitialAd`.